# How to plot stacked bar chart according to the custom Y axis in D3

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have a stacked bar chart where I have to show data% within 0 to 100.
for example - if a, b have value 3, 7 out of 10 then I have to show it as 30% and 70%. But sometimes the data comes under 1%, so I modified the Y-axis as below which is equally distributed but not able to put the chart according to the custom Y-axis.

[custom Yaxis chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mHEpV.png)

This is how I modified the Y-axis using D3

```
var y_data = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,30,50,70,100];

var y = d3.scaleLinear()
  .domain([0, 100])
  .range([height, 0])
  svg.append("g").attr('class', 'y-stack')
  .call(d3.axisLeft(y).tickValues(y_data).tickSize(10).tickPadding(10));

d3.select('.y-stack').selectAll('.tick').each(function(i, val) {
  const temp_height = height + margin.top + margin.bottom - margin.left;
  const diff = temp_height / (y_data.length - 1);
  $(<any>this).attr('transform', 'translate(0, ' + (temp_height - (diff * val ) + 0.5 + ')'));
});
```

Now how do I plot the chart or is there any easy way to do it instead of making a custom calc function for it.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that by providing arrays of `n` domain values (the `y_ticks` you gave) and `n` range values (the number of pixels from 0 along the axis). Then it will also automatically interpolate for example 15 to be on 25% between 10 and 30.

I got the base code from [here](https://bl.ocks.org/LemoNode/5a64865728c6059ed89388b5f83d6b67):

```js
var data = [{
    "State": "AL",
    "Under 5 Years": 52,
    "5 to 13 Years": 29,
    "14 to 17 Years": 10
  },
  {
    "State": "AK",
    "Under 5 Years": 56,
    "5 to 13 Years": 21,
    "14 to 17 Years": 20
  },
  {
    "State": "AZ",
    "Under 5 Years": 28,
    "5 to 13 Years": 62,
    "14 to 17 Years": 15
  },
  {
    "State": "AR",
    "Under 5 Years": 43,
    "5 to 13 Years": 17,
    "14 to 17 Years": 20
  },
  {
    "State": "CA",
    "Under 5 Years": 49,
    "5 to 13 Years": 15,
    "14 to 17 Years": 30
  },
  {
    "State": "CO",
    "Under 5 Years": 87,
    "5 to 13 Years": 1,
    "14 to 17 Years": 11
  }
];

var keys = Object.keys(data[0]).slice(2);
var states = [...new Set(data.map(d => d.State))]
var yTicks = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,30,50,70,100];

function getRange(from, to) {
  const interpolator = d3.interpolate(from, to);
  return new Array(yTicks.length)
    .fill(undefined)
    .map((_, i) => interpolator(i / yTicks.length));
}

var svg = d3.select("#chart"),
  margin = {
    top: 35,
    left: 35,
    bottom: 0,
    right: 0
  },
  width = +svg.attr("width") - margin.left - margin.right,
  height = +svg.attr("height") - margin.top - margin.bottom;

var x = d3.scaleBand()
  .range([margin.left, width - margin.right])
  .padding(0.1)

var y = d3.scaleLinear()
  .range(getRange(height - margin.bottom, margin.top))
  .domain(yTicks)

var xAxis = svg.append("g")
  .attr("transform", `translate(0,${height - margin.bottom})`)
  .attr("class", "x-axis")

var yAxis = svg.append("g")
  .attr("transform", `translate(${margin.left},0)`)
  .attr("class", "y-axis")

var z = d3.scaleOrdinal()
  .range(["steelblue", "darkorange", "lightblue"])
  .domain(keys);

data.forEach(function(d) {
  d.total = d3.sum(keys, k => +d[k])
  return d
});

svg.selectAll(".y-axis")
  .call(d3.axisLeft(y).tickValues(yTicks))

data.sort((a, b) => states.indexOf(a.State) - states.indexOf(b.State))

x.domain(data.map(d => d.State));

svg.selectAll(".x-axis")
  .call(d3.axisBottom(x).tickSizeOuter(0))

var group = svg.selectAll("g.layer")
  .data(d3.stack().keys(keys)(data), d => d.key)

group.exit().remove()

group.enter().append("g")
  .classed("layer", true)
  .attr("fill", d => z(d.key));

var bars = svg.selectAll("g.layer").selectAll("rect")
  .data(d => d, e => e.data.State);

bars.exit().remove()

bars.enter().append("rect")
  .attr("width", x.bandwidth())
  .merge(bars)
  .attr("x", d => x(d.data.State))
  .attr("y", d => y(d[1]))
  .attr("height", d => y(d[0]) - y(d[1]))

var text = svg.selectAll(".text")
  .data(data, d => d.State);

text.exit().remove()

text.enter().append("text")
  .attr("class", "text")
  .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
  .merge(text)
  .attr("x", d => x(d.State) + x.bandwidth() / 2)
  .attr("y", d => y(d.total) - 5)
  .text(d => d.total)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.js"></script>
<svg id="chart" width="650" height="400"></svg>
```